# Task queue java

Tags: java, api, google-app-engine, queue, task

Hi i'm new to Task queue concepts when i referred the guide I got struck on this line

```
queue.add(
      DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService().getCurrentTransaction(),
      TaskOptions().url("/path/to/my/worker"));
```

what is `TaskOptions()` method. Is it default method are method created manually what will `TaskOptions()` method will return.

I created a method called `TaskOption()` when i to return a string value its saying error as `"The method url(String) is undefined for the type String"`

In url what i want to specify servlet are any other.

My doubt may be stupid but please clarify it.

Thank you,
sharun.

Comment: I added the google-app-engine tag since this question is in the app engine realm.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a bug in the doco to me.  My guess is what they meant was to use [TaskOptions.Builder](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/labs/taskqueue/TaskOptions.Builder.html) which is a class full of static methods to make it easy to create TaskOptions.  So the [code example](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview.html#Task_Within_Transactions) should probably look like this:

```
queue.add(
     DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService().getCurrentTransaction(),
     TaskOptions.Builder.url("/path/to/my/worker"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports.  You may be importing the incorrect Queue class.

If your Queue is imported via

```
import com.google.appengine.api.labs.taskqueue.Queue;
```

then `queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.url(""))` method exists.

If your Queue is imported via

```
import com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.Queue;
```

then will you will receive the error.